# Can't access the web on a BlackBerry after BES activation

Tags: blackberry

What should a user do who can't access the web on a BlackBerry after BES activation? (Having email and other information syncing via the BEs requires a working data connection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One recommendation is to check the policy implemented by the BES administrator.  The BES may gate Internet access by the devices so this is where I would start.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the device's default browser must be changed:

- Close the browser (using the menu option - the "back" key basically just minimizes it)
- Go into Options, Advanced Options, Browser
- Change the "Default Browser Configuration" options to "Internet Browser."
- Click the "Menu" button on the device and save the settings
- Reopen the browser

Comment: Leaving breadcrumbs for others - add your own solutions if you like.